# Create a file that attaches to the lifetime of the process in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking for away to create a file that is attached for the life time of the process, and **that another process can access it**.

Assume process A that creates a file, assume process B that can access this file (so it needs to know its location) , now when process A is being shutdown (no matter the cause) the file is being deleted.

As far as I can tell [tmpfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) is not good enough as process B would not be able to locate the file (in trivial way)

Any other ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To attach the file lifetime with the process lifetime you can use signal handling (Cf. [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/signal.html)). You just need to call

```
signal(SIGTERM, your_deleting_file_method)
```

inside the A process. By doing this you are free to define a static filename if it meets your need.